# Display image from database using file directory

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

[image]I want to display the image from the folder to the webpage. The image directory is already saved on the database. The MySQL query is correct. The syntax can display the image directory but cannot able to display the image.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head 
content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Profile |CRB</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media 
queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js">
</script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">
</script>
<![endif]-->
</head>


<body>
<?php include 'header.php' ?>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">                  <!-- NAV TABS -->
<li role="presentation"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="trucks.php">Trucks</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="suppliers.php">Suppliers</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="clients.php">Clients</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="accountspayables.php">Uploaded Files</a>
</li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="maintenance.php">Maintenance</a></li>
<!--  DROPDOWN start -->
<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" 
aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  About us <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li role="presentation"><a href="contactus.php">Contact us</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="aboutus.php">About us</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<!-- END OF DROPDOWN --> 
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['started']) && $_SESSION['started']) {

}
?>

<li role="presentation" class="dropdown pull-right">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="" role="button" 
aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="cursor: pointer;" aria-
hidden="true"> <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li role="presentation"><a href="">Settings</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="pull-right" class="active"><a href="profile.php"><?php echo  
$_SESSION['user'];?></a></li>
</ul>
<!--  end of HEADER -->
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">

<?php include 'config.php'; 
if(isset($_SESSION['started']) && $_SESSION['started']) {

}
$val = '';  
$query="SELECT USER_PHOTOPATH FROM useraccounts WHERE USER_NAME = 
'".$_SESSION['user']."' ";
$stmt  = $conn->prepare($query); 
$stmt  -> bindParam(1,$val);
$stmt  -> execute();

$row   = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row['USER_PHOTOPATH'];
?>

<img src="<?php echo $row['USER_PHOTOPATH']; ?>;">  <!-- I TRIED THIS SYNTAX 
TO DISPLAY THE IMAGE -->
</div>

<?php 

?>
<div class="col-sm-4">

<h1 class="text-primary">My Profile</h1>

<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as 
needed -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us an `echo $row['USER_PHOTOPATH'];` so we can see an example of what you have stored in the database

Comment: Can you explain what this code is there for `if(isset($_SESSION['started']) && $_SESSION['started']) {

}` as it appears to be doing nothing

Comment: Have you checked on the image path ?

Comment: Pretty sure this is going to be a simple case of not adding the path to the filename in the `src` attribute. So please edit your question with the output of `echo $row['USER_PHOTOPATH'];`

Comment: I provided a screenshot. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove `;` after completing `?>` php
`<img src="<?php echo $row['USER_PHOTOPATH']; ?>;">`